# Using <AttrViewExprs> tag of ADF Bindings

Tags: jsf, model-binding, oracle-adf

> In **af:selectOneChoice** component have a list of employees, with the
>   display of their full name, and it great works. How to make sure that
>   the **af:selectOneChoice** component output instead of the full name
>   of the employee of his abbreviated name, i.e. first letter of the
>   first name and full last name? And I need it to do without modify the
>   Employees entity. A good solution would be if it were done to
>   employeesPageDef page definition. Perhaps this can be done using a
>    tag, but I do not know how to work and meet the documentation I could not find. Tell me please: how can I solve this
>   problem, and give instructions on how to use the 
>   tag in the page definition.

Please provide as an example of using the AttrViewExprs tag in Page Definition (ADF Bindings).

Comment: So you have for example: Steven Castle and you want to display it as S. Castle in your SOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Map` to populate a `f:selectItems`.

In your managed bean do something like this:

```
public class Bean
{
    private Map<String, Employee> employees;

    public Map<String, Employee> getEmployees()
    {
        if (employees == null)
        {
            initMap();
        }
        return employees;
    }

    private void initMap()
    {
        //get list of employees and put in map
        employees = new HashMap<String, Employee>;
        for (Employee e : someClass.getAllEmployees())
        {
            String name = e.getFirstName().subString(0,1);
            name += ". ";
            name += e.getLastName(); 
            employees.put(name, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your JSF page you can use:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.employees}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Per Duncan Mills: Why not use the JSTL substring expression to do this?
e.g.

```
 <af:outputText value="#{fn:substring(row.bindings.FirstName.inputValue,0,1)}"/>
```

inside a table would just print the first letter of each employees name.

You need to include the JSTL functions taglib in your project  and add this to the

```
jsp:root definition:
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions
```

"